# I'm aiming to send a vCard through Twilio without the help of a virtual machine or ngrok. Is this possible?

Tags: twilio

I don't have a virtual machine set up, so sending a vCard with the help of ngrok is not possible. I would like to know if there is a simpler way to send a vCard. If it helps, the contact information I'll be sending will always be the same phone number.

I explored the Twilio blog about sending a vCard by hosting code in a virtual machine and using ngrok. This doesn't work for me yet, because I'm not running a virtual machine that is always on. I'm new to this, so its possible that a simple solution is being overlooked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sending messages with media through the Twilio REST API requires that the media be available to Twilio's servers as you are not able to upload the media within your original request. This can be seen in the *Include Media in Your Messages* example here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages#include-media-in-your-messages

Example snippet:

```
message = client.messages.create(
  body='Hello there!',
  from_='+15555555555',
  media_url=['https://demo.twilio.com/owl.png'],
  to='+12316851234'
)
```

As a workaround to spinning up your own VM or VPS, you would be able to use Twilio Assets within a Serverless project to upload and store your vcard file. This makes it available to Twilio's REST API via a public or protected URL (based on your configuration) that you can pass in your REST API request!

Twilio - Support - Getting Started with Assets: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019105433-Getting-Started-with-Twilio-Assets